# Param causing 404

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, errors, 404-error

I just moved over from blogger and which added ?m=1 and ?m=0 params on a lot of urls, and they are currently saved on a lot of social media, bookmarks, etc. All requests coming in with m=x in the params cause 404s!

I found out that m= is a reserved Wordpress param, but the suggested 'fix' in all questions that I found answers to was to use a different param name which I cannot do since the urls are out there. I tried adding a .htaccess 'fix' (below) which 'works' but I would prefer to not add another redirect to the chain.

Are there any ways to properly fix this so that URLs with m= do not give 404s and do not redirect?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any docs on what the `m` parameter does in blogger and examples of the kinds of URLs you need to handle? `m` appears to be used for months in WordPress

Comment: Blogger uses m=1 as mobile and m=0 as not mobile.